# How to make several instances of nivo slider in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript

I develop a web site using the Drupal 7 cms. I use [Nivo Slider](https://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) and it works perfectly for me. I used nivo slider for the front page of the site. When I configured the nivo slider it's settings are displayed under structure in the Drupal CMS menu. Basically, I have to update images and set transitions and etc.

Now the problem is I have another page where I need to add a new slideshow. But I don't know how to make another instance of nivo slider and use it. Since this is a CMS I guess there should be a easy way to handle this.

I think my problem is clear. If not, please ask in comments where I have to clarify my problem.

Comment: Do you want show the same slideshow in another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Views Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) module. It allows you to construct the slider using views. Since you can create blocks with views, you should be able to build several galleries (by creating other views).